# Gaussian Curve equation in R not peaking at zero

Tags: r, normal-distribution, ggplot2

I have been analysing and plotting some different Gaussian curves in R to help me visualise them for a project I am working on. One such expression is the following:

[image]

In R I have plotted this with by writing the following function:

```
f2Liu <- function(x) {
  exp(-0.5*(x / 10000)^2) - exp(-0.5) / (1 - exp(-0.5))
}
```

When I visualise the plot it does not peak at zero which is what I expected so am wondering if I have used the incorrect syntax for the function in R?

The plot looks like the following and is labelled "*Curve 2*".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add parentheses in the numerator.

*f2Liu <- function(x) {
(exp(-0.5*(x / 10000)^2) - exp(-0.5)) / (1 - exp(-0.5))
}*

As it is currently written, the function in your code computes the following function:

$$
f(d_{ij},d) = e^{-0.5*(\frac{d_{ij}}{d})^2} - e^{-0.5}/(1-e^{-0.5}).
$$

Comment: Brilliant thanks - back to school for me!